# Passing props to components in React Navigation v5 dynamic component configuration

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

In my app, I am displaying a login screen if the user is not logged in, and a logged-in screen if the user is logged in. In the simple example below, you can see that I am checking if the `jwt` and `user` exists in my redux store and then displaying the appropriate screen.

```
type Props = {
    +jwt: string | null;
    +user: UserModel | null;
};

export class AuthStackNavigator extends Component<Props> {

    renderScreen() {

        if (this.props.jwt && this.props.user) {
            return (
                <Stack.Screen name={'AuthenticatedView'} component={AuthenticatedView} />
            );
        } else {
            return (
                <Stack.Screen name={'LoginView'} component={LoginView} />
            );
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Stack.Navigator>
                {this.renderScreen()}
            </Stack.Navigator>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        jwt: getJwt(state),
        user: getUser(state)
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AuthStackNavigator);
```

You can see that the `AuthenticatedView` component is rendered if the `jwt` and `user` exists. Inside `AuthenticatedView`, I am currently getting the `user` from the redux store again where it is possibly null - this involves another check. Is there a way I can pass the `user` to the component as a prop from `<Stack.Screen>` as I know it exists here? This way I do not have to make the same check multiple times.

I'm aware that you can send data to components when navigating using:`navigation.navigate('View', props)`, but I do not navigate to this screen using this function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the official documentation https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation/#passing-additional-props

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't find this because I was looking in the API ref where there's no mention of it

Comment: link is broken?

Comment: Ha this was exactly what I needed to hear XD